# Solving “combined labor problems” with calculus

Tags: calculus

I always enjoyed the [combined labor problems](https://www.wikihow.com/Solve-Combined-Labor-Problems) I’d see in algebra classes.

One day our calculus teacher said something like, “Remember those combined labor rate problems?  Here’s how you do it in calculus!  They become pretty straight forward…”

I can’t remember the approach and I can’t find any calculus solutions online, only the algebraic ones using inverses.

Here’s a sample, taken from the link given above:

> "If Tommy can paint a room in 3 hours, and Winnie can paint the same room in 4 hours, how long will it take them to paint the room together?”

What is the calculus approach?

Comment: I suspect it's absolutely no different, just writing a rate like room/hr as a derivative and using the fact that you add Tommy's rate and Winnie's rate to get the combined rate. This is what you do with the simple algebra.